# Should I somewhat normalize/scale data less than 1 when squared

Tags: data-transformation

I'm using a simplification algorithm for Geo-points where internally a squared distance between points is calculated. I have the feeling that the outcome is somehow strange and it might be because it makes a big difference whether the distance of two points is less than or greater than 1 Meter. The whole algorithm seems to struggle, because small distances get even much smaller squared distances while other become much greater.

This problem should occur quite often in statistical calculations, since many very basic formulae or algorithms calculate squares quite often.

**Is it generally necessary or advisable to scale data before calculations**, e.g. use cm instead of m? Does this usually have any effect? Maybe in some cases this effect is even desired?!

Background:

Unfortunately I don't have an environment where I could use R or Matlab. It's **running in the browser hand-crafted with JavaScript**. But I'm asking not only for this special case, but generally, because I'm self-teaching statistics and R. It's a really big universe you're in, compared to computer programming which seems like a small village to me.

BTW I'm using http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/ for simplification.

Comment: Depends on which methods you are using. With scale-invariant methods, using m or cm would not affect the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're concerned about – correct me if I'm wrong – is that if $x > 1$, $x^2 > x$, whereas if $x < 1$, $x^2 < x$.

I don't know of a method where this in itself would be an issue.

The reason is: you don't ever compare $x^2$ and $x$. They have different units. Yes, it feels different to square a small number, but if you just look at a plot of $y = x^2$, there's nothing different about $x=1$. The algorithm doesn't care.

There are two main ways in which scaling can matter:

- If you have multiple variables, scaling changes the relative importance between them. Imagine you have data points that include both a location and a time, and you compute distances between those data points according to the standard Euclidean distance. If you measure the location in nanometers and the time in years, the difference in location is going to be numerically much larger and it'll dominate the distance. If you measure location in parsecs and time in milliseconds, it'll be the other way around.
- Numerical issues. If the numbers you're using are very small, the limited-accuracy floating point data types our programs usually use start causing more and more issues. The issue @Lennart brought up is one of these. In practice, this typically really matters only when your numbers are quite small, when they vary over many orders of magnitude, or (for some algorithms) when the implementation is naive.

---

That said, using squared distances does absolutely magnify the importance of large distances. Sometimes this is what you want; sometimes it's not, especially when there's a reasonable chance of outliers. Exactly what to do about that, if that's a problem, depends a lot on what algorithm you're using. One example is to use "Huberized" functions, which are quadratic out to a certain value and then become linear ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss)).

Scaling doesn't affect this problem. If the issue is that $y^2$ is much bigger than $x^2$, note that $\frac{(a y)^2}{(ax)^2}=\frac{y^2}{x^2}$, so their relative sizes are unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of singular (or nearly singular) matrices. It may also be because the condition number is large. But if you calculate it in Matlab it shouldn't be a problem because it QR-factorizes the matrices by default, thus, the condition number won't be as large. What program are you calculating the algorithm in?

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question. Can I understand "factorize" like some kind of scaling?

Comment: It's a scalar as in A = QR  where Q is the (under) orthogonal matrix and R the upper triangular matrix. You can calculate the euclidean distance in matlab using X=[Geo-points] with the command D = pdist(X) or D = pdist(X,distance).